# More formal word for "mover and shaker"

Tags: idioms, synonyms

Is there a more formal word or phrase for *mover and shaker?* Single word is preferred.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since [*mover and shaker*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/mover+and+shaker) means a person who wields power and influence in a certain field, these words might work:

- [Magnate](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/magnate)
- [Mogul](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/mogul) (applicable definition is number three, for the second entry)

Answer (score 3):

*Movers and Shakers* are people of influence, so you can call them, in abbreviated form if necessary, *the influential*, as in 'The influential in the United States, as in all countries, are those with money, power and popularity.'